# How to unit-test NSFetchedResultsController in Swift

Tags: unit-testing, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, xctest

I have a Swift app that uses `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch `List` objects from persistent store:

```
let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = ...
var error : NSError?
fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error)
if let error = error {
    NSLog("Error: \(error)")
}
let lists: [List] = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects! as [List]
NSLog("lists count = \(lists.count)")
for list: List in lists {
    NSLog("List: \(list.description)")
}
```

and it works like expected, I am getting `List` objects descriptions printed out to the console.
I would like to write some unit tests for my app, so I created class that extends `XCTestCase`. The code compiles without a problem, tests runs, but unfortunately I am not able to fetch the `List` objects in that context.

All I am getting in the console is count of `List` objects and a fatal error:

```
lists count = 59
fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

rised by the line:

```
for list: List in lists {
```

I am pretty sure I have targets configured properly, as I can create `List` object and insert it into managed object context without a problem from my app's source code as well as from unit test source code. The only problem I am experiencing is with fetching from test unit. I wonder why fetching is working when running the app in the simulator and fails when executed during unit test.

Any ideas what could be wrong will be appreciated.

**Update:**

To be more specific how my implementation looks like, here is complete code sample that I am playing with:

```
var error: NSError? = nil

let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let applicationDocumentsDirectory = urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL

let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CheckLists", withExtension: "momd")!
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)

var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
let url = applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CheckLists.sqlite")
if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
    NSLog("Error1: \(error)")
    abort()
}

var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true) ]

let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
    fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
    managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext,
    sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
    cacheName: "ListFetchedResultsControllerCache"
)

fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error)
if let error = error {
    NSLog("Error2: \(error)")
    abort()
}

let fetchedObjects: [AnyObject]? = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
if let fetchedObjects = fetchedObjects {
    NSLog("Fetched objects count: \(fetchedObjects.count)")
    for fetchedObject in fetchedObjects {
        NSLog("Fetched object: \(fetchedObject.description)")
    }
}
else {
    NSLog("Fetched objects array is nil")
}

let fetchedLists: [List]? = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as? [List]
if let fetchedLists = fetchedLists {
    NSLog("Fetched lists count: \(fetchedLists.count)")
    for fetchedList in fetchedLists {
        NSLog("Fetched list: \(fetchedList.description)")
    }
}
else {
    NSLog("Fetched lists array is nil")
}
```

When I execute it from my app's source code, running the app in simulator, the console output looks like this:

```
Fetched objects count: 3
Fetched object: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a6866f0> (entity: List; id: 0x7a686020 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p2> ; data: {
    name = "List 1";
})
Fetched object: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a686930> (entity: List; id: 0x7a686030 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p1> ; data: {
    name = "List 2";
})
Fetched object: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a686970> (entity: List; id: 0x7a686040 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p3> ; data: {
    name = "List 3";
})
Fetched lists count: 3
Fetched list: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a6866f0> (entity: List; id: 0x7a686020 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p2> ; data: {
    name = "List 1";
})
Fetched list: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a686930> (entity: List; id: 0x7a686030 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p1> ; data: {
    name = "List 2";
})
Fetched list: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a686970> (entity: List; id: 0x7a686040 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p3> ; data: {
    name = "List 3";
})
```

However, when I execute this code from a unit-test, I am getting this output:

```
Fetched objects count: 3
Fetched object: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a07df50> (entity: List; id: 0x7a07d7e0 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p2> ; data: {
    name = "List 1";
})
Fetched object: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a07e190> (entity: List; id: 0x7a07d7f0 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p1> ; data: {
    name = "List 2";
})
Fetched object: <CheckLists.List: 0x7a07e1d0> (entity: List; id: 0x7a07d800 <x-coredata://7A87B5BE-C2FA-4150-B9E3-879FDE07F0B9/List/p3> ; data: {
    name = "List 3";
})
Fetched lists array is nil
```

I hope it makes easier to understand where the problem is. Somehow, this statement:

```
let fetchedLists: [List]? = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as? [List]
```

produces an array of `List` objects when app is run in the simulator, but it fails producing `nil` when executed from unit test.

Comment: Do you have your object-model ('momd') file included in your test bundle? And is the model file setup to use your 'List' subclass for the list entity?

Comment: @MrAlek - I am not sure if my `.momd` file is included in test bundle. I am creating model like that: `NSManagedObjectModel(NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CheckLists", withExtension: "momd")!)` and it's working for main target as well as test target. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @MrAlek - In my `.xcdatamodeld` file I have set up correct class for `List` entity. I can even create new entity in my unit tests and insert it into context. It persist in database when context is saved.

Comment: @MrAlek - I have updated the question with more detailed sample code and explanation where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is connected with targets configuration. I have solved the problem with a little workaround.

Previously, in order to make `List` entity class accessible in my unit test target, I have added it to this target. So, the `List` class was in two targets. In fact, there were two `List` classes known by Swift, one for each target: `MyAppTarget.List` and `MyUnitTestTarget.List`. Retched results controller returns array of `MyAppTarget.List` objects, but in unit test target, `List` was assumed to be `MyUnitTestTarget.List` class. That's way this line of code:

```
let fetchedLists: [List]? = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as? [List]
```

produced `nil` when executed from unit test target, and not the proper array as when executed from main target. To fix that I just changed it to:

```
let fetchedLists: [MyAppTarget.List]? = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as? [MyAppTarget.List]
```

and make the `List` class public. After that change, it works like expected.

But still, it is a little bit confusing for me that `MyAppTarget.List` cannot be casted to `MyUnitTestTarget.List`. Moreover, it means that I need to make public every entity `NSManagedObject` subclass in order to use it inside unit tests. So far I didn't find better solution.

Perhaps there is a better way to solve that issue. I don't see an option to tell `NSFetchedResultsController` that it should return `MyAppTarget.List` in main target, and `MyUnitTestTarget.List` in unit test target. It will always use configuration from the `.xcdatamodeld` file for given entity. Also, even if there is a way to cast `MyAppTarget.List` into `MyUnitTestTarget.List` inside a unit test, it will still require the `List` class to be public.

**Update:**

I have found a way for changing class of entities returned by `NSFetchedResultsController` in runtime. It's a more clear and simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858758/514181

It allows to seamlessly use CoreData entities in unit tests, without casting or making entity class public.

Comment: Do you have an example anywhere? I tried this approach but got back errors saying that the class wasn't found so it was using NSManagedObject instead

Comment: I have attached example source code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25858758/514181

Comment: I tried that but no joy. I have a simple example at https://github.com/ztolley/Frazzle