# How to change managed object class name before fetching

Tags: core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I have a Swift app that uses CoreData. I created `List` entity with class `MyAppTarget.List`. Everything is configured properly in .xcdatamodeld file. In order to fetch my entities from persistent store, I am using `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true) ]
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "ListFetchedResultsControllerCache")
```

and it works like expected, returning array of `MyAppTarget.List` objects when fetching.

However, I would like to use it inside another target, for unit testing. I added `List` class to `MyUnitTestTarget`, so I can access it inside the unit test target. The problem is that the fetched results controller returns `MyAppTarget.List` objects, not the `MyUnitTestTarget.List` objects. In order to make the `List` entity testable, I have to make it public along with all methods that I need to use and I would like to avoid this.

I tried to change the `managedObjectClassName` property on `NSEntityDescription`:

```
fetchRequest.entity.managedObjectClassName = "MyUnitTestTarget.List"
```

but it generates exception:

> failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Can't modify an immutable model."

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/index.html) states that

> [...] once a description is used (when the managed object model to which it belongs is associated with a persistent store coordinator), it must not (indeed cannot) be changed. [...] If you need to modify a model that is in use, create a copy, modify the copy, and then discard the objects with the old model.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this flow. I wonder if there is a way to change the managed object class name in runtime, before fetching the entities with `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Answer (score 5):

It occurs that solution to my problem was pretty simple. In order to make it working, I had to create a copy of managedObjectModel, edit its entities and create `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` with the new model. Changing the `managedObjectClassName` property on `NSEntityDescription` instance is possible only before model to which it belongs is associated with `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

```
    let testManagedObjectModel = managedObjectModel.copy() as NSManagedObjectModel
    for entity in testManagedObjectModel.entities as [NSEntityDescription] {
        if entity.name == "List" {
            entity.managedObjectClassName = "CheckListsTests.List"
        }
    }
```

This also solves [my other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25815117/514181) with unit testing CoreData model entities in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically alter the class name of the `NSManagedObject` subclass with something like:

```
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles([NSBundle.mainBundle()])!

    // Check if it is within the test environment
    let environment = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment as! [String : AnyObject]
    let isTestEnvironment = (environment["XCInjectBundle"] as? String)?.pathExtension == "xctest"

    // Create the module name based on product name 
    let productName:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as! String
    let moduleName = (isTestEnvironment) ? productName + "Tests" : productName

    let newManagedObjectModel:NSManagedObjectModel = managedObjectModel.copy() as! NSManagedObjectModel

    for entity in newManagedObjectModel.entities as! [NSEntityDescription] {
        entity.managedObjectClassName = "\(moduleName).\(entity.name!)"
    }
```