# Why is executeFetchRequest not returning subclass objects when run under XCTest using Swift?

Tags: core-data, swift, xctest

I have a Swift project using CoreData with subclasses of NSManagedObject setup. These have a class name setup (in xcdatamodel view) which includes as the class the main target name "MainTarget.MyEntity" as per . Everything works well when running the app. However, I went to add in some Unit Tests with XCTest and the app started crashing with ERR_BAD_ACCESS or ERR_BAD_INSTRUCTION when casting the result of executeFetchRequest to the proper type. I also tried casting each element in the array, and this also causes a crash. Error is nil in all my test cases.

```
var entities = _managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [MyEntity]?
```

The above results in : "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type" on the console.

```
var entities = _managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
let e = entities[0] // Works fine
let ee = e as NSManagedObject // Works fine
let eee = e as MyEntity // Crash: Exception breakpoint, then ERR_BAD_ACCESS - no messages on console
```

The above results in a crash, but only when invoked from a unit test!

I have two targets, one main target and one test target (normal default setup). The NSManagedObject classes are selected to be in both targets so that they are accessible to the tests. These subclasses are written in Swift, no Objective-C.

During the Unit Tests I am using an in memory persistentStoreCoordinator (though I tried with the same one setup in AppDelegate with the same result).

The debugger for Swift is just about useless (sorry had to vent). When I look at the variable for the array returned by executeFetchRequest, it does not expand to show the elements, and any attempts to 'po' it or its contents crashes XCode completely - that coupled with SourceKit crashing every 3 minutes has made for a very frustrating day...but I digress. The only useful bit of information that I can gleam is that the array returned is of TestTarget.MyEntity instead of MainTarget.MyEntity. I presume, while casting, it's trying to cast to MainTarget.MyEnity (since the code under test resides in MainTarget) , and thus the crash on the attempt.

It seems like such a basic thing to be able to unit test code that involves Core Data, I can't believe how frustrating this has been. Has anyone been able to get XCTests to  work with NSManagedObject subclasses? How do you get CoreData to return the right subclasses in the MainTarget instead of those in the TestTarget?

Some other things I tried include:

1. Adding the @objc(MyEntity) annotation to the subclasses, but this caused an message from Core Data about the class not being found and therefore returning NSManagedObject instances (which are obviously not castable to the subclasses)
2. The suggestions linked to and mentioned here: [How to unit-test NSFetchedResultsController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815117/how-to-unit-test-nsfetchedresultscontroller-in-swift)
3. Suggestions here: [executeFetchRequest throw fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897122/executefetchrequest-throw-fatal-error-nsarray-element-failed-to-match-the-swift)
4. Banging head against wall until dizzy. I recommend against this measure, it wasn't very productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar question. Making my entity class public solves the issue and I get the right class type.([CoreData class miss match in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27132533/602948))

Comment: Yes, this was the only way that I could solve it. I don't like that all my entities and their vars are public, it feels wrong, but nothing else I tried worked.

Answer (score 1):

*i concur: the issue is pure hell. debugger is no help.*

the workaround as described in @madcat's answer, with one essential addition is to:

1. have the model class and its properties **public**

   ```
   public class MyManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
       @NSManaged public var myProperty: String
   ```
2. do **not** have the model on the test target
3. import the projects production target (by default: Project Name) in the XCTest

   ```
   import TargetName
   ```
4. either define the classes in the model with `TargetName.MyManagedObject` or use `@objc()` annotation in the model classes:

   ```
   @objc(MyManagedObject)
   public class MyManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
   ```

---

**Swift 2**: As of Swift 2 the model properties do **not** have to be **public** anymore. for this import the project with: `@testable import TargetName`.

> […] a unit test target can access any internal entity, if you mark the import declaration for a product module with the @testable attribute and compile that product module with testing enabled.

*from [The Swift Programming Language: Access Control – Access Levels for Unit Test Targets](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)*

Comment: I can't remove the managed object from my test target, because other classes that are also on the test target use that object. And because those classes are regular target classes, I can't import TargetName in them.

Comment: have you found another solution? i'd also rather not have the classes imported and public. isn't it possible to import the target to itself?

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed from your debugger, the issue is that when running the test, the subclass of the `NSManagedObject` is actually `<Product Name>Tests.<Subclass Name>` instead of `<Product Name>.<Subclass Name>`. One way to solve this is to dynamically alter the class name of the `NSManagedObject` subclass with something like:

```
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles([NSBundle.mainBundle()])!

    // Check if it is within the test environment
    let environment = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment as! [String : AnyObject]
    let isTestEnvironment = (environment["XCInjectBundle"] as? String)?.pathExtension == "xctest"

    // Create the module name based on product name 
    let productName:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as! String
    let moduleName = (isTestEnvironment) ? productName + "Tests" : productName

    let newManagedObjectModel:NSManagedObjectModel = managedObjectModel.copy() as! NSManagedObjectModel

    for entity in newManagedObjectModel.entities as! [NSEntityDescription] {
        entity.managedObjectClassName = "\(moduleName).\(entity.name!)"
    }
```

This helps to workaround the class name mismatch.