# CoreData class miss match in unit test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, swift

When i try to retrieve an array of items from my model I always get an down cast error, because of a mismatch of the types of the classes. Swift has a strict namespace and the model items are different  than the items I want to cat into. Here is my NSManagedObject:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Boss)
class Boss: NSManagedObject {    
    @NSManaged var name: String
}
```

The Testclass is following:

```
func testCheckIfFetchGetTheCorrectClass() {
   // setup item
   let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Boss", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
   let boss = Boss(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

  boss.name = "Chef"

  var bosses = [Boss]()

  var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Boss")
  var e: NSError?
  if let results = moc.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &e) {
    println("results: \n\(results.description)\nCount:\(results.count)")
    if let downcastedSwiftArray = results as? [Boss] {
      // downcastedSwiftArray contains only UIView objects
      bosses = downcastedSwiftArray
    } else  {
      XCTAssert(false, "Down Cast Error")
    }
    println("Bosses : \n\(bosses.description)")
  } else {
    println("fetch error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
    abort();
  }

    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
}
```

When I run the test following types will show up in the debugger:

```
bosses  [NameSpaceTestTests.Boss]   0 values        
results [AnyObject] 1 value 
  [0]   Boss_Boss_ *
```

So it looks like the `result` array contains a `Boss` class item that will not match the `bosses`
array.

How can I assign the result of the fetch request to my array?

You will find the complete project on [github](https://github.com/dirkfabisch/NameSpaceTest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Making your classes `public` is a workaround and should not be needed for test dependencies.

The problem really is that the test target compiles his own version of the source classes, which isn't what you want. You'll end up with two versions of the same.

The following steps fixed it for me:

### Remove all 'normal' classes from the test target compile list

[image]

---

### Make sure the Module name for the app and test app are different (i.e. `App` and `AppTests`

[image]
[image]

---

### Make sure you import the app module in every test

[image]

Comment: If you are seeing a Swift Decodable error of "The given data did not contain a top-level value" when trying to unit tests `Core Data` objects that implement `Decodable`, this is your issue: Core Data xcdatamodel and all model objects should only be included in main target (NOT in the unit test target) and marked as `public` (which the are by default in autogenerated classes) or `internal` with `@testable import`, otherwise you will get strange errors in your unit tests.

Comment: Best answer ever!

Answer (score 4):

If you change

```
if let downcastedSwiftArray = results as? [Boss] {
```

to force downcast to

```
if let downcastedSwiftArray = results as! [Boss] {
```

does your test abort due to a runtime error?

I had problems downcasting to Core Data managed object types as well. Adding the `NSManagedObject` sublcasses' files to the test target made the code compile but didn't seem to work properly. **So don't add code under test to the test target itself. Import it.**

### With Swift 2: Use `@testable`

Before Swift introduced the `@testable import`, we were forced to make classes we wanted to test public. That exposed far more of our code to client than we'd want. Nowadays, this is the way to go.

### Before Swift 2: Make the class public

I solved this by making the classes `public`:

```
@objc(Boss)
public class Boss: NSManagedObject {    
    @NSManaged public var name: String
}
```

Then import the production module in tests:

```
import MyProjectTargetName
```

Comment: The Option 1 is working. Thanks! I have updated the GITHUB Project for reference.

Comment: Great! Please consider updating your question and rephrase it to prevent further downvotes (which I don't understand, honestly)

Comment: Option 2 does NOT work. A manually added bridging-header does not solve the namespace trouble. (Option 1 works for me, too.)

Comment: Had no luck, either, so I removed this option. Thanks!

Comment: Don't make everything public. I mean really, just exposing your entire API to test it doesn't seem very logical does it? See my answer above to see how to set up the project the way I think you're supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! The advice was outdated. I added an updated remark.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you have to specify the Type of the array resulting from a fetch request. The if let pattern requires an optional cast.

```
if let result = moc.executeFetchRequest(request, error:&e) as? [Boss] {
    // use result
}
```

Comment: If tested it and now I get no results at all. The code works like charm if I use it when the target is not the test target. It seems, that I get different name spaces, depending on the build targets.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to dynamically alter the class name of the `NSManagedObject` subclass with something like:

```
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles([NSBundle.mainBundle()])!

    // Check if it is within the test environment
    let environment = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment as! [String : AnyObject]
    let isTestEnvironment = (environment["XCInjectBundle"] as? String)?.pathExtension == "xctest"

    // Create the module name based on product name 
    let productName:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as! String
    let moduleName = (isTestEnvironment) ? productName + "Tests" : productName

    let newManagedObjectModel:NSManagedObjectModel = managedObjectModel.copy() as! NSManagedObjectModel

    for entity in newManagedObjectModel.entities as! [NSEntityDescription] {
        entity.managedObjectClassName = "\(moduleName).\(entity.name!)"
    }
```

This helps to workaround the class name mismatch because when running the test, the class name is actually `<Product Name>Tests.<Subclass Name>` (in your case, it's `NameSpaceTestTests.Boss`)